# How to compare a slice with other slices to see if the contents matches

Tags: go

Using Go 1.11 I have 5 group of three numbers each in their own slice. I want to be able to compare that to a core data set.

Example data

```
My Groups: [[1 2 3] [4 9 2] [7 9 3] [4 7 5] [4 3 2]]

My Core Data: [5 9 7 3 2]
```

So I want to be able to match my core data up with any of the groups. As the example data shows, the core data does have 9, 7 and 3 so it should match the 3rd group.

But each time I try to loop, I am not getting the logic right.

Any help most welcome.

UPDATE

So this is the code I am currently working with

```
groupData := [][]int{{1,2,3}, {7,8,9}, {9,7,3}}
coreData := []int{5,9,7,3,2}

for _, data := range groupData {
   fmt.Println( data )
   fmt.Println( groupData )

   fmt.Println( reflect.DeepEqual(data, coreData) )
}
```

This returns false all the time. Even on the last set of data `9,7,3` which you can see is contained within the `codeData` var.

But even if I had a `coreData` like `[]int{3,2,7,1,9}` that should still result in true, as it still has 3,7,9 and I want to it match that last group.

Hope that explains what I am looking to do more.
Thanks.

Comment: is not a duplicate - it ask when slices are equal in length, that is a simple compare, I want to check, in a simple way, two slices of different length - unless thats the same thing?

Comment: no, it is not. and it seems that your question is to check if elements in a given slice is a subset of the comparing slice. it is not a simple _content matche_ problem, and maybe you should elaborate your intention with examples. FYI: I deleted my misleading comment.

Comment: I have updated my answer to respect your need of partial match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an update of my previous answer because you need a partial match.

As you want to have a partial match you cannot use deep equals.

But you can do something like this.

```
func main() {
    groupData := [][]int{{1,2,3}, {7,8,9}, {9,7,3}}
    coreData := []int{5,9,7,3,2}
    
    // Loop over each group to check a partial match against core
    for _, data := range groupData {
       fmt.Println( check(data, coreData ))

    }
}

func check(group, core[]int) bool {
    // Loop over each group element to check if its available in core
    for _, s := range group{
        if contains(core, s) == false {
            return false
        }   
    }
    return true
}

// Returns true if core contains the element
func contains(core []int, element int) bool {
    for _, a := range core {
        if a == element {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

This result in :

> false
>
> false
>
> true

Comment: They need a partial match